# Getting Script to exit if Get-Content is denied or not found

Tags: powershell

so I am working on a small script comparing two files using the Get-Content. So far things are somewhat working, but one small caveat.  I would like to have the script give an *error and stop* if the get-content for $location is not found or denied.  I was thinking some kind of if statement for this, but am having difficultly.

```
if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($location)){

write-host "please input a valid path"
exit
```

Update - There is an input value $location that you put in let say c:\test\test.txt. The way the current script works it is takes that input and put it into the "(Get-Content -Path $location)". If you enter a correct path and file this works and the script continues and says "Comparison complete". But if you enter a location and file that doesn't exist lets says c:\awoieroiuaf the script continues on and give and error Get- Content : Cannot find path 'C:\pscript\hashgenv4.ps1 C:\Test2 c:\awoieroiuaf' because it does not exist.

And then it says "Comparison is complete". As I said before I would like to test the user input first to determine that the path exists before going on with the script.

And tried several different methods.

```
}    
else
{

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $title2hashstorage/$sha256) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $location)| Out-GridView


Write-host "Comparison is complete"
}                                        
exit
```

Comment: what difficulty are you having?

Comment: Just use Test-Path $location to see if it exists

Comment: Test-Path worked!  Thank you!  Slowly but surely I will learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a terminating error for get-content:

```
'one'
get-content foo -erroraction stop
'three'
```